# Server 2008 - Host SMB on one NIC only (without Windows Firewall)

Tags: nic, server-message-block, cifs

First post here.

I have a client with a Server 2008 R2 machine that hosts an SMBv2 share, as well as a non-Windows service on a secondary NIC. We don't want SMB connections to hit the secondary NIC, but Windows firewall is specifically disable... and cannot be enabled.

We tried disabling NetBIOS over TCP for that NIC, but are still seeing SMB connnections to it.

In a perfect world, we could either 1) utilize Windows Firewall, 2) prevent SMB traffic from hitting that box altogether, or 3) configure SMB multichannel configuration through PowerShell (not available in 2008).

I've been looking if there is a way to do this via netsh ipsec static add filter, but don't think that will work either. I've also been looking at various configs in the registry for the SMB service (as you would imagine you could specify the IP for 445 to listen on), but haven't run across anything that can specify an IP.

Ideally, when I run: 
netstat -an | findstr 445

I don't want to see:
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

...just the specific IP of the first NIC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just untick "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" on the NIC in question?

Comment: That is a very good question! Trying now.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks!

How do I mark this as "answered"?

Comment: I've posted an answer, you can accept it by ticking the checkbox to its left.

Answer (score 1):

To disable SMB on a network connection, untick "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" in the Properties dialog.  This can be opened from Network Connections by right-clicking on the connection and selecting Properties.  The relevant dialog looks like this:

[image: Local Area Connection Properties dialog]